# How can I send email via facebook?

Tags: sendmail

How can I send email via facebook?
The api notifications.sendEmail has been disabled.

Comment: Maybe ask the facebook helpdesk? There might have a reason for disableing it?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook disabled the **notifications.sendEmail**.

You'll need to ask for user's permission to access his Email address [Facebook Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) and then when you have his email address you should implement your own email address sender.

I can give you an example of an email sender, just let me know what langauge you use.